# SVN related, in relation to the "trunk / branches" concept

Tags: python, svn, testing, software-design

I have been experimenting with SVN for a while. I have a little test project in order to test different aspect of being an SVN administrator and an SVN user. Here is a bit of introduction first.

I have a script:

```
<repos>/python/testScript/trunk/testScript.py
```

this script checks an environment variable $LOCALSITE and lists the result. Today I have found a bug which simply breaks the script if that env. variable is not set. So I immediately branched to:

```
<repos>/python/testScript/branches/branch-00.01.xx/testScript.py
```

and also pushed a tag:

```
<repos>/python/testScript/tags/0.1.1/testScript.py
```

So this first tag is still inheriting the bug of "Failure in case $LOCALSITE is not set." just as the trunk is still suffering from the same problem.

The reason that I have pushed a tag is that I am %100 sure that this script will be executed in an environment that will have the $LOCALSITE set-up correctly. So it will not break. And people can keep using "tag-0.1.1" as usual.

However I still want to fix that problem. So here is the question:

I have fixed and tested the problem on "branch-00.01.xx/testScript.py", so now I know that "branch-00.01.xx" is working, unless there are more hidden bugs. Was that the correct step? or should I have fixed the trunk?

Now what should I do? Should I push the fixed branch to a new tag? or should I fix the trunk and kill the branch "branch-00.01.xx"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch model assumes that when you are done working on a feature, you will merge it back into the trunk. There's no need to tag it, since you don't want to expose it to the outside world. (In reality you could have done this fix directly on the trunk, but I understand that you're exploring the process).

Since you're just getting started, I suggest you take a look at mercurial: Its syntax is pretty svn-like, but it's the next generation of "distributed" version control. I don't mean to trash-talk svn, it's a great system, but this is something you'll want to know about too.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it later and it seems like this is what I should have done: Fix the trunk. Thanks. And yes, I am trying to simulate an svn experience.

Comment: Branches are also appropriate for bugfixes (or for new features), if the trunk is likely to change before the bugfix is completed. When I work on my own I only use them for major experiments, since I'm likely to do minor fixes to the trunk before the experiment is done. Also to isolate the experiment in case it fails and I end up putting it aside (but might want to come back and cherry-pick from it later).

Answer (score 0):

At some level it doesn't matter what you choose because trunk / branch are just logical concepts (names) for convenience and have no technical difference.

In my experience, you usually think of trunk where you do your latest and greatest development, while leaving branches for versions you have already pushed to customers and may need to work on later, but don't want to worry about ongoing trunk changes breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

Different sites go about this in different ways.  A lot of it is a policy matter.

The best way I've seen, IMO:

1) Trunk is a relative free-for-all, but there may be a policy that nothing can be checked into trunk without first running automated tests.  This tends to reduce people waiting on trunk to work well enough to test unrelated changes.

2) A branch is still changing, but will gradually slow down on the changes. Things checked into trunk may be evaluated for checkin to related branches.  After a while, a branch may be "frozen", EG by setting up a commit hook that rejects all commits that don't include some magic cookie in a checkin.  This is easy to get around if someone wants to badly enough (by looking at commit history), but it eliminates accidental checkins to frozen branches.

3) When a given branch is looking pretty stable, it gets copied to a tag before it's packaged up for Q/A.  The tags never change once created, as a point of reference - even though in theory SVN treats them as equally changeable - the difference, again, is a matter of policy.

The annoying part of all this is SVN external references.  If you have none, branching and tagging is easy - just svn copy and you're done.  If you have them, you tend to end up writing a script to adjust the external references as part of the branching/tagging process.  But external references are really useful sometimes.  I've been experimenting with "internalizing" all my external references during branching - IOW duplicating all external references as part of the newly created branch, to keep branching and tagging simple.  Then developers need to check things into more places when there's an important fix, but so far it seems to be more of help than a hindrance, at least in my personal projects.